# shift the rest of the line to a newline after a space

Tags: bash, perl, unix, sed, tr

if I have the following:

```
>AB ABABABA
>AC ACACACA
```

how do I shift everything onto a newline after the space i.e.

```
>AB
ABABABABA
>AC
ACACACACA
```

I have tried:

```
cat file | sed 's/ /\n/g'
cat file | tr ' ' '\n'
```

however I get the exact same output.

** UPDATE **

Upon inspecting the file using less and nano, the output was different to using cat. The file contains some terminal escape characters that aren't displayed in cat, but are in less. (how does this even happen?)

This was a terrible bug to spot and everyone has actually posted corrected answers based on the output of cat. So thank you for your help. Could the mods close this one?

Comment: `sed 's/ /\n/g' file` should work

Comment: @anubhava As well should the `tr`, at least with the test data. One might want to use `$'\n'` for literal newline though.

Comment: the weird thing is - that I have tried this (see question) and it doesn;t work. I am completely baffled!

Comment: Do you have a tab there or is it really a space. Try `sed 's/ /xxx/'`.

Comment: @brucezepplin  I didn't see your comment above when I posted my answer -- did you try with something other than the literal space, like `\s` (in Perl) that matches any kind of space?

Comment: @brucezepplin, "it doesn't work" is the most useless problem description -- you need to show us **how** it doesn't work? What is your *actual output*?

Comment: @brucezepplin  Your examples show the pattern before the space being repeated on (copied to) the next line.   I added to my answer so to do that as well. Please clarify.

Comment: Example on "_UPDATE_" and "_how does this even happen_".  Try this in a shell: `echo "\033[31mhey"`.  It should print `hey` in red. The `\033` (escape) and `[` start an ANSI escape sequence, `m` ends it, and `31` specifies red.  Now put this in a file.  Some tools emit this raw so terminal produces colored text, like `cat` and `grep`.  Some don't, and we see literal characters, like `less` (`less -R` or `-r` does, see man page).  There are many escapes (you can move the cursor, for example),  and some don't have an obvious effect. Some may simply not work. So we don't see that they are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to replace (any kind of) space with a newline

```
perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/' data.txt
```

This produces the required output in my tests. The `-p` sets up the loop over input (opening files or using `STDIN`) and sets `$_` to the current line. It also prints `$_` each time after processing.

If there are multiple spaces, each to be replaced by `\n`, add `/g` modifier.

If there may be more to do you can also capture patterns and replace them

```
perl -pe 's/\s+(.*)/\n$1/' data.txt
```

---

Following the observation in the [answer by glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949358/4653379) and looking "*more closely*" it appears that the first word on the line need be copied to the next line.  Then the above is modified to

```
perl -pe 's/^>(\S+)\K\s+/\n$1';
```

The `\K` is a particular form of the [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which *asserts* that the pattern preceeds the current match position but it discards all previous matches (so you don't have to capture and copy them). You can find it [in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). Without it the `>(\S+)` would be consumed so it would have to be copied back in the replacement part, as `/>$1\n$1/`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to move the content from before the space onto the next line as well?

As in `>A BC` becomes:

```
>A
ABC
```

Then one can use sed like this:

```
$ sed 'h;s/^>\([^ ]*\) /\1/;x;s/ .*/ /;G' file
>AB 
ABABABABA
>AC 
ACACACACA
```

Breakdown:

```
h;                                # Copy pattern space to hold buffer
  s/^>\([^ ]*\) /\1/;             # Convert >A BC to ABC 
                     x;           # eXchange hold buffer and pattern space
                       s/ .*/ /;  # Remove everything after, but including the
                                  # first space: >A BC -> >A
                                G # Append hold buffer to pattern space
```

Comment: definately just a single space

Comment: That is indeed `***ed up sed`, we may disagree on what the `*`s represent :-). What's the point? Its just so much simpler, more efficient, more portable, more easily extensible and better in every other way to do things like this in awk. Let all the arcane sed constructs die and stick with what it's good for - `s/x/y/`.

Comment: @EdMorton AFAIK POSIX sed doesn't strictly specify `\n` in the replacement part. And this substitutes spaces for newlines. Please show me how this would be done with awk, as your answer doesn't show it.

Comment: @EdMorton The sed above changes `>abc def` to `>abc abcdef` where the space is a newline. I answered the question with a question, since OP expected output is saying that what they want.

Comment: Well, so he is. He cunningly camouflaged his output by using sequences of the same 2 characters to make it hard for us to see what he was doing with them. Not sure that was a great way to get answers but there y'go. OK, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking more closely it looks like you want to repeat the first word on the next line: to transform this

```
>foo bar
>baz qux
```

into this

```
>foo
foobar
>baz
bazqux
```

If that's true, you can do

```
sed -r 's/^>([^ ]+) />\1\n\1/' file  # or
perl -pe 's/^>(\S+) />$1\n$1/' file
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^>(\S+)\K\s+/\n$1/' file`

Comment: Does POSIX sed specify `\n` in the replacement, isn't that implementation specific? POSIX sed specified `\n` in search part though. One should consider using `sed -E` as it's supported by Free BSD as well as GNU, while `sed -r` is GNU only.

Comment: To how many different operating systems are you planning to deploy your script? IMO, POSIX compliance is of limited value if you are sticking to a single OS.

Comment: @glennjackman That was not my question. I'm genially interested in knowing.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{print $1 ORS substr($1,2) $2}' file
>AB
ABABABABA
>AC
ACACACACA
```